# A dot appears as i click on link-UI issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Firefox- windows-XP- A dot is appearing as you click on like link.

1) When i Log in the site,
2) Enter search criteria,
3) Now click on "Like" link,
 Result:-a dot is appearing only at the time of liking
the response.

Its an UI issue, dot appears only when the link is clicked i.e when focus is on the link.
Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Where is this dot appearing? Can you show us the HTML? (That's where the issue is likely to be, of course... the fact that you're generating it in Rails is almost bound to be irrelevant.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this is an outline which appears by default in Firefox when focusing on the element. If so, this CSS might be what you are after. As Jon says, though, it's impossible to say without a link or some code at least.

```
:focus, :active { outline: 0; }
```